# I need to stop my for loop but break won't work

Tags: python, position

I have written some code that finds the position of the word a user enters in a sentence. But after they enter the word I need the code to find the position and print it and then stop there. But it doesn't stop instead it continues onto the else statement which is what happens if they enter a word that isn't in the sentence. If i use break it only prints the first position of a word if it appears more than once in the sentence. What should i do?

```
sentence = "ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country"
print(sentence)
keyword = input("Input a keyword from the sentence: ").lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if keyword == word:
        print("The position of %s in the sentence is %s" % (keyword,i+1))


if keyword != word:
    keyword2 = input("That was an invalid input. Please enter a word that is in the sentence: ").lower()
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if keyword2 == word:
             print("The position of %s is %s" % (keyword2,i+1))
```

Comment: If the word appears more than once, do you want the each position of word?

Comment: Use the `break` command when your condition is satisfied.

Comment: You might want to just wrap it in a function and return the value when found. Then just print the returned value when calling the function. That way you'll also be able to reuse it in other instances without needing to recode it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just get all the indexes first, then do your second function only if there are no matching indexes.

```
indexes = [i for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == keyword]
if indexes:
    for i in indexes:
        print('The position is {}'.format(i))

if not indexes:
    ...
```

You could also use a `while` loop so that you can just use a single step.

```
keyword = input("Please enter a word that is in the sentence: ").lower()
indexes = [i for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == keyword]
while not indexes:
    keyword = input("That was an invalid input. Please enter a word that is in the sentence: ").lower()
    indexes = [i for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == keyword]

for i in indexes:
    print('The position is {}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a question about the while loop example, I want to understand how it is actually solving my problem, like how does it print both positions then stop before printing an error message. What is the purpose of the list comprehension?

Comment: The only error condition is if the provided keyword is not in the list of words.  The list comprehension gets a list of all matching indexes in the sentence for the provided keyword.  If the list produced from that list comprehension is empty, then the keyword didn't match any words and you need to re-prompt the user to enter another keyword.  Once the keyword matches at least one index, `indexes` will evaluate to `True` and cause it to break out of the `while` loop.  Then it will print all the matching indexes.

Comment: Thank you so much mate you're a lifesaver! xx